# AddThis code don't work in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

I copied and paste **AddThis** code to a **.aspx**,  but when I run the **.aspx**, I get error. why? Thanks!

```
Warning 1   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): This attribute name must be followed by an equal (=) sign and a value. If the value is in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match. 
C:\Users\CW\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite5\Default.aspx 16  44  C:\...\WebSite5\
```

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=mycwcgr"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: liekly its complaning about those additional attributes.

Comment: did you saw this?: http://forums.asp.net/t/1618102.aspx/1

Answer (score 2):

try setting them like this:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" <%="fb:like:layout" %>="button_count"></a><!--Facebook Like-->

<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" <%="g:plusone:size" %>="medium"></a><!--Google Plus-->
```

most probably it is complaining only because of those 2